# Closes Files after selecting multiple videos

Tags: pantheon-files, video-player

I have a problem with" Files "- I select 3 or more video files with the mouse, then RMB for any of the files, then select" open in Video "in the menu , then" Files " is closed. Okay!
Who can help. 
I installed codecs and even Parole - I do not know what to sin. If there's anything I need to report on my system, I'm ready.

Comment: Which app are you opening with?  I do not get a crash with the native Videos app, but if I use Gnome MPV player then it crashes.

Comment: @JeremyWootten, native Videos

Comment: What version of Files are you using (latest is 4.1.3)?  What type(s) of video does this happen with?  Are the selected videos all of the same type?

Comment: @JeremyWootten, I'm using Files version 4.1.3 (io.elementary.files --version). For example, I select 3 or more files in the *.mkv format, cartoons))) Yes, all files are of the same type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have raised an issue regarding this at https://github.com/elementary/files/issues/856 and will push a PR to fix it shortly.